# css fixed menu overlaps the content

Tags: javascript, css

I have a top menu which must be always visible so i've used position:fixed. It works and the menu is always on top of the window.
The problem comes with the content, the next div with a big image gets cut by the menu:

```
#header {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
```

You can see the menu in this link:

```
http://212.48.86.94/~admin/el-cuartel-gana-el-tercer-premio-mejor-agencia-independiente-en-los-premios-control-2014/
```

I've tried modifying positions, overflows and everything in firebug with no luck.

Also the wp theme i'm modifying does some javascript calculations for the height and uses an on scroll event.

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: If you menu has a fixed height, you can use that same amount as a margin- or padding-top for the first content element, or padding-top for body or something. If it doesn’t – then you will either have to calculate the height, or not position it fixed in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to your hero wrapper just add a margin..

```
#hero-wrapper{
    margin-top: 68px;
}
```

this will offset the width of your fixed header

a few other notes...

line 2549 has a console.log() you should remove that.

```
console.log('dentro1');
```

line 2551 of your main.js throws an error when scrolling

```
$categoryHash = document.URL.split('?')[1].replace( /^filter=/, '' );

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

Comment: i added margin-top: 67px to other divs not that. Stupid me :)

Comment: What if your navbar/header can vary in size? Mine scales depending on the resolution, a fixed margin is only barely a solution.

Comment: This problem was related to a fixed size. If you'd like me to help I'm happy to, but this is 5 years old so I don't remember all the details. Care to post a jsfiddle or something for me to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `margin-top: 100px` or whatever value your header is to your CSS.  That will make sure your content doesn't get covered up at the top of the page.  You could try something like this:

```css
#nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
.content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="nav">Welcome</div>
<div class="content">bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>bla
  <br>
```

I hope this helps.  Let me know in the comments below if you need additional help.